# How can I keep td elements from wrapping in a table row

Tags: css, html

I have a table row (tr) with many table data (td) elements, but when the page is resized horizontally, I want a scroll bar to appear at the bottom as opposed to wrapping the td elements.

I've tried setting the following css, but it doesn't seem to help:

```
td {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

You can see an example at:  http://jsfiddle.net/EaVTP/

Any ideas?

Thanks

**Edit**
It turns out that I didn't need "nowrap", the style that I was missing was "overflow" and I had inherited a "width=100%" which was conflicting.

Comment: Take a look at this example --> http://jsfiddle.net/EaVTP/2/ You need more text in one line for this rule to work. I think you'll need to give static width for your `tr` or `table` for scroll-bar to appear.

Comment: It does that by default, but you need to write valid HTML first: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EaVTP/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `min-width` on your table itself:

```
table {
    min-width:200px;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EaVTP/3/)